# Why does adding Bevel Depth to a Curve result in 2 objects?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

This is easy to replicate. Open Blender, delete default cube etc and add a Curve. Notice that nr of selected Objects is 1/1. Go to Object Data Properties and add Bevel Depth to the curve. Now nr of selected Objects is 2/2. Why?

Comment: I presume this is because the bevel result is a mesh... but good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as @lemon says, because the bevel depth creates a mesh object - although only procedural and temporary until you set it back to 0, but as long as it is there you have a curve and a mesh object.

Blender also takes procedural meshes from modifiers into account. Something similar for example:

When you take the default cube, it is 1 object with 8 vertices. After adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier at *Level* = 1 to it, the statistics now show 1 object with 26 vertices, although going in *Edit Mode* you see, those vertices are still just 8, the 26 are the procedural vertices. Toggling visibility of the modifier on/off will also change the vertices between 26 and 8.

But, when you use for example an *Array* modifier, the object count does not increase. Why? Because even when the meshes are far enough apart to not be merged, when you apply the modifier you still have one object but with multiple separate meshes.

And here is the difference to the curve: the bevel depth is a mesh, but the curve underneath is a curve. A single object cannot hold curve and mesh data at the same time, so they are treated (and shown) as two objects. I do not know why exactly it is not seen as just a mesh temporarily, probably because in *Edit Mode* you have the curve and the mesh on top of it - or even when converting the beveled curve to a mesh, you have the option to keep the original so that you now have curve and mesh as two actual separate objects.

At least this makes some sense to me. If there is more to it, for the real reasons you might have to ask the developers, we are just users here.

Comment: I assume it is intentional, but it is confusing. For instance, to know how many parts a model is made of, you'd select all your objects in the outliner and trust that the number of objects shown in the status bar is correct.

Comment: @Roderick Hm, no actually I would never do that. I use the _Statistics_ overlay in the _3D Viewport_ which always shows me how many objects, vertices, edges and faces there are even without the need to select them. And to have an idea how heavy a scene is for rendering, the overall face count might be much more interesting than the number of objects. Because when rendering a scene with for example 1,000,000 faces it doesn't make much of a difference if they are produced by 99 or 100 objects.